# How to set a multiple button on a one image (4x4)

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to divide a picture into 4x4 and it should have a 16 buttons.

As of now I have created 3x3 buttons alone (without picture).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/back_orange" >
 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_marginTop="130dp"
     android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
     android:layout_width="300dp" android:weightSum="1"
     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="300dp">
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="0.33" android:layout_height="0dp">
         <Button android:id="@+id/Button04" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
         <Button android:id="@+id/Button05" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
         <Button android:id="@+id/Button06" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="0.33" android:layout_height="0dp">
         <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
         <Button android:id="@+id/Button02" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
         <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" android:text="Button" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="0.33" android:layout_height="0dp">
         <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
         <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
         <Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:text="Button" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></Button>
     </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: For example, consider a picture a class room. If a touch a button it should say it is pen, table, etc..

Comment: If you have 3x3, why can't you make 4x4 in a similar way. Although you might want to use GridView (or RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager) for that, so you don't have to use Nested Weights